# How to get mode name using XCB?

Tags: x11, xcb, xrandr

In Xlib the structure `XRRModeInfo` contains, aside from `nameLength` field, the `name` itself. But in XCB the corresponding structure `xcb_randr_mode_info_t` only contains `name_len`, and there seems to be no function to get actual name string.

I do see all the mode names in the string returned by `xcb_randr_get_screen_resources_names()`, but they are all concatenated, and I don't know how to find the offset of a particular mode in this string.

So, how can I get the mode name using XCB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I do see all the mode names in the string returned by xcb_randr_get_screen_resources_names(), but they are all concatenated, and I don't know how to find the offset of a particular mode in this string.

You have the length of the individual names and you know the length of each name, so you just have to count bytes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <xcb/randr.h>

int main()
{
        xcb_connection_t *c = xcb_connect(NULL, NULL);
        xcb_screen_t *screen = xcb_setup_roots_iterator(xcb_get_setup(c)).data;
        // TODO: Error handling
        // TODO: Checking if the RandR extension is available
        xcb_randr_get_screen_resources_reply_t *reply =
                xcb_randr_get_screen_resources_reply(c,
                                xcb_randr_get_screen_resources(c, screen->root),
                                NULL);
        xcb_randr_mode_info_iterator_t iter = xcb_randr_get_screen_resources_modes_iterator(reply);
        uint8_t *names = xcb_randr_get_screen_resources_names(reply);
        while (iter.rem) {
                xcb_randr_mode_info_t *mode = iter.data;
                printf("Mode %d has size %dx%d and name %.*s\n",
                                mode->id, mode->width, mode->height, mode->name_len, names);
                names += mode->name_len;
                xcb_randr_mode_info_next(&iter);
        }
        free(reply);
        xcb_disconnect(c);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ah, so there's no O(1) way (in the mode count) to do this, right?

Comment: Two answers: (1) Nope (2) Are you really worried about the performance of getting the mode names? That should be always so fast that it does not matter.

Comment: Actually, a third one: You can make your own lookup-table for this stuff. This table can be constructed in time O(n) (assuming memory allocation is in O(1)). This way, you basically get what Xlib does for you. With XCB, you just get the raw "on-the-wire" bytes without any parsing or shuffling stuff around. So, in a way, XCB is better here since it makes the parsing cost more apparent.

Comment: I was concerned not with performance per se, but rather whether `libxcb-randr` has already done some processing that this loop is re-doing. Now, after reading actual source of `randr.c` from `libxcb` I see that, indeed, `xcb_randr_get_screen_resources_reply_t` is the fixed-length part of the server output returned by `xcb_wait_for_reply()`, so XCB is a rather thin wrapper that can't have already done this processing. Thus your answer is fine.

Comment: This also explains *why* the API is so weird. (It just does not explain why the protocol is so weird...)